# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Partial postback doubles a jqueryUI progress bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a view that has a partial view in it, everything works fine, but there's an odd glitch that whenever a user reloads the partial view, the main view gets a double progress bar that on there.

the progress bar is a JqueryUI progress bar, and the kicker is, each time a partial refresh is done, it adds to the issue.

to clarify, the progress bar isn't in the partial view.

not at all sure what in terms of code to show, so if you need to see something specific, let me know.

thanks.

Comment: If you take your senerio and reduce it most basic functionality: a View with a partial view with "hello world", you may uers are better able to help. you may also see the issue will jump out at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are the js files being double included multiple times? maybe once in the page, and again in the partial?  that can cause problems like this

Comment: that was it, i had the partial view reload the main view instead of the partial, duh! thank you so much.